# setting onmouseenter to be a function with argument

Tags: javascript, function-pointers, onmouseover

Im trying to set the onmouseenter function for all child divs of an element in a ready callback. So the onload of body is

```
    function ready(){
      for(var i=0;i<document.getElementById("pieces").childNodes.length;i++){
    var n=document.getElementById("pieces").childNodes.item(i);
    n.onmouseenter=function(){showBorder(n);};
    n.onmouseleave=hideBorder;
     }
    }
```

but all of the divs that get its onmouseenter function set use value of n that occurs at the end of the loop. I want each onmouseenter to use the value of n at the time the callback is set.

What can I do?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the handlers are bound to the same, single `n`. Therefore changing `n` changes the `n` for *all* handlers.

What you can do is "localize" `n` by passing `n` to an immediate function that is executed on every iteration. This makes `n` of each handler bound to the `n` of the immediate function, and not to the `n` of the function `ready`

```
function ready() {
    var n;
    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById("pieces").childNodes.length; i++) {

        //the local n takes precedence over the outer n
        //therefore any use of n in the immediate function refers to the local n
        (function(n) {

            //you can actually name the variable anything you want
            //but to override the outer n, we use n for our local n

            n = document.getElementById("pieces").childNodes.item(i);
            n.onmouseenter = function() {
                showBorder(n);
            };
            n.onmouseleave = hideBorder;
        }(n));
    }
}​
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast - that was exactly what I was trying to find out too - Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has function-level scope so the declaration of the variable `n` (but **not** the assignment of `document.getElementById('pieces').childNodes.item(i)` to `n`) within your `for` loop is actually hoisted to the top of `ready` function.

To understand this, imagine that your code is actually written like this since this is how the JavaScript engine actually interprets it:

```
function ready() {
    var i, n;
    for (i = 0; i < document.getElementById('pieces').childNodes.length; i++) {
        n = document.getElementById("pieces").childNodes.item(i);
        n.onmouseenter = function () { showBorder(n); };
        n.onmouseleave = hideBorder;
    }
}
```

The assignment of `function () { showBorder(n); }` to `n`'s `onmouseenter` property creates a closure such that when that anonymous function actually executes it will have access to any and all data that was in scope at the time of creation, i.e. when the `ready` function is invoked. Thus, every one of those `onmouseenter` methods will have a reference to the variable `n` which, by the time `ready`'s execution is complete, has a value equivalent to `document.getElementById('pieces').childNodes.length`.

I would suggest the following code snippet:

```
function ready() {
    var pieces, i, l, n;
    pieces = document.getElementById('pieces').childNodes;
    for (i = 0, l = pieces.length; i < l; i++) {
        n = pieces.item(i);
        n.addEventListener('mouseover', (function (m) {
            showBorder(m);
        })(n), false);
        n.addEventListener('mouseout', hideBorder, false);
    }
}
```

1. Declare all variables at the top of the scope so there's no confusion about their scope within the function context.
2. Lookup `document.getElementById('pieces').childNodes` *once* and assign that memory location to the `pieces` variable to avoid another lookup every time you need to reference that set of nodes.
3. The comparison statement in the `for` loop is executed *every* iteration so instead of looking up `pieces.length` repeatedly assign it to the variable `l` once and reference that variable each time instead.
4. The use of `on<event>` methods of a DOM element is, for the most part, the worst way to assign event handlers if for nothing else because you can only have a single function registered to a given DOM element at any time. The `addEventListener` method is the preferable way to assign handlers unless you expect your users to have an older version of Internet Explorer which instead uses the `attachEvent` method.
5. The `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events were not standard DOM events but rather custom events added by Microsoft for older versions of Internet Explorer. They were added to the DOM Level 3 specification and Firefox and Opera introduced support for these events, but Webkit still does not support them.